# Full screen windows form but with title bar

Tags: c#, .net

I am following this article, http://www.vesic.org/english/blog-eng/net/full-screen-maximize/

This makes my windows form to go full screen but it also hides Title bar.

I want to hide task bar but like to have my title bar.

"    targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;" hides my title bar but removing this shows task bar so is there anyway to hide task  bar and keep title bar in windows app? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myClasses
{

    public class WinApi
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemMetrics")]
        public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int which);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void
            SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter,
                         int X, int Y, int width, int height, uint flags);

        private const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
        private const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;
        private static IntPtr HWND_TOP = IntPtr.Zero;
        private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 64; // 0x0040

        public static int ScreenX
        {
            get { return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN); }
        }

        public static int ScreenY
        {
            get { return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN); }
        }

        public static void SetWinFullScreen(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class used to preserve / restore state of the form
    /// </summary>
    public class FormState
    {
        private FormWindowState winState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        private FormBorderStyle brdStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        private bool topMost;
        private Rectangle bounds;

        private bool IsMaximized = false;

        public void Maximize(Form targetForm)
        {
            if (!IsMaximized)
            {
                IsMaximized = true;
                Save(targetForm);
                targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

                targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                //targetForm.TopMost = true;
                WinApi.SetWinFullScreen(targetForm.Handle);
            }
        }

        public void Save(Form targetForm)
        {
            winState = targetForm.WindowState;
            brdStyle = targetForm.FormBorderStyle;
            topMost = targetForm.TopMost;
            bounds = targetForm.Bounds;
        }

        public void Restore(Form targetForm)
        {
            targetForm.WindowState = winState;
            targetForm.FormBorderStyle = brdStyle;
            targetForm.TopMost = topMost;
            targetForm.Bounds = bounds;
            IsMaximized = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean "Full screen windows form but with task bar" right ? (in you Q. heading)

Comment: Without taskbar but with toolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it to `FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;`, than only the taskbar is hidden.

Comment: This shows the titlebar, but surprisingly the maximise and minimise buttons are not seen on titlebar whereas close is present. How to get these button back

Comment: targetForm.MinimizeBox = true; and targetForm.MaximizeBox = true; doesn't work

Comment: Yes, that's because you have a fixed window. If you allow the user to change the size. You'll get the buttons back. Unfortunately, there is no FormBorderStyle for your wanted behavior. You may have to write one yourself.

Comment: is this a very unique requirement? I thought many developers need this.Any pointers to some article/blog? Thanks anyways

Comment: I sayed thats an unique requirement because I cant find anything to solve your problem. Sry.

Comment: No problem @Leon. Thanks for ur support